# Grouping lines together in a file

Tags: python

I have a file like this, i want to sort it by the string that is enclosed in {} but i need to keep the set of 3 lines together.

```
bot_out_c_dn_l_za
meta{c_4x8__end}  (bot_lq_b_c_dn_l1_za),
meta{c_4x8_end}  (bot_lq_b_c_dn_l0_za);
bot_out_c_dn_l_za
meta{c_4x8_gps}  (bot_rq_b_c_dn_l1_za),
bot_out__c_dn_r_za
meta{c_4x8_end}  (bot_lq_b_c_dn_r1_),
meta{c_4x8_end}  (bot_lq_b_c_dn_r0_);
```

I was thinking of parsing the file, looking for semi columns, joining the 3 lines into one string, then splitting the string on the kyeword meta and sorting it by the keyword.

When i try to concatenate, it gives me an error-

```
listoflines={}
i=0
for line in file:
    if ";" in line:
        listoflines[i]+=line
        i=i+1
    else:
        listoflines[i]+=line
```

The error is -
IndexError: list index out of range
Happens at the very first index (i=0).

Comment: what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces a list of lines in the order specified.

```
import re
import itertools

lines = f.readlines()
order = [x[0] for x in sorted(enumerate(lines[1::3]), key=lambda x: re.match('.*\{(.*)\}.*', x[1]).groups()[0])]
sorted_lines = list(itertools.chain(*[lines[i*3: (i+1)*3] for i in order]))
```

Comment: I want to write each group to its own file, how do i find where the sorted lines/order data structure changes group?

Comment: Do you mean groups of 3, or are you considering all groups of 3 that have the same key to be a group?

Comment: Groups of 3 have the same key to be a group

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure you item exists in your dictionary before you can add to it

```
listoflines={}
i=0
for line in file:
    if ";" in line:
        try:
            listoflines[i]+=line
        except IndexError:
            listoflines[i]=line
        i=i+1           
    else:
        try:
            listoflines[i]+=line
        except IndexError:
            listoflines[i] = line
```

you could also shorten this considerably

```
listoflines={}
i=0
for line in file:
    try:
        listoflines[i]+=line
    except IndexError:
        listoflines[i]=line
    if ";" in line:
        i = i + 1
```

or using defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
listoflines=defaultdict(str)
i=0
for line in file:
    listoflines[i]+=line
    if ";" in line:
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: Instead of the second alternative I would rather use a [`defaultdict(str)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - with that the OPs original code would pretty much work unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = open("temp.txt","r").readlines()
triples = zip(lines[0::3],lines[1::3],lines[2::3])
sorted_lines =  map(lambda x: "".join(x), sorted(triples, key=lambda x: x[1]))
print( "".join(sorted_lines) )
```

Comment: This isn't really sorting on the text contained in the curly braces.

Comment: thanks, does the lambda function sort on the first item ? I want it to sort on the keyword after {} , sjhould i do something like map(lambda x: "".join(x), sorted(triples, key=lambda x: x[2].split(("{"))[1])

Comment: You can just sort on the second of each triple because of the state structure of the input file.  Remember, strings are compared lexicographically.  Unless the problem description is misleading, the proposed sort should be correct.